# How do I get the max rowkey in HBase?

Tags: filter, hadoop, hbase, max, key-value

How do I get the max `rowkey` in an HBase table?

I have a table with two rows:

```
TT-0001 column=cf:col-1, timestamp=1341218075789, value=abc
TT-0002 column=cf:col-1, timestamp=1341218075789, value=abc
```

I want to get row2 (maxvalue of rowkey).

How do I do this in Hbase?

Answer (score 1):

With ur chosen row-key u could just simply return the "last" row of ur table and print out just the row key (as I assume that u just increase the numbers behind "TT-"). You can also make use of the [KeyOnlyFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/KeyOnlyFilter.html) that will emit the value and u can use ur own method to check which row key is the greatest.

u should probably check out [rowkey design](http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html), especially section 6.3.3 of the provided link, 
 as I wouldn't recommend a row key like u r generating. As outlined in the named section the latest, most current, row will be the first one.

Answer (score 1):

getRowOrBefore() method of HTable class will help us in doing this. For ex,

```
HTable table=new HTable(conf,"test");
Result result=table.getRowOrBefore(Bytes.toBytes("TT-9999"),Bytes.toBytes("colfam"));
System.out.println(Bytes.toString(result.getRow()));
```

Comment: The API documentation states that this method (getRowOrBefore) is deprecated without replacement. (https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTableInterface.html#getRowOrBefore%28byte[],%20byte[]%29 ).